# Issues with apt upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm running the following command: `sudo apt upgrade`

And the following error pops up:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up policykit-1 (0.105-31+deb11u1) ...
chown: cannot access '/usr/libexec/polkit-agent-helper-1': No such file or direc
tory
dpkg: error processing package policykit-1 (--configure):
 installed policykit-1 package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 depends on policykit-1 (>= 0.105-5~); however:
  Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packagekit:
 packagekit depends on policykit-1; however:
  Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package packagekit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packagekit-tools:
 packagekit-tools depends on packagekit (= 1.2.2-2); however:
  Package packagekit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package packagekit-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer1.0-packagekit:
 gstreamer1.0-packagekit depends on packagekit (= 1.2.2-2); however:
  Package packagekit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer1.0-packagekit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 policykit-1
 gdm3
 packagekit
 packagekit-tools
 gstreamer1.0-packagekit
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After trying `sudo aptitude install -f`, the following error appears:

```
The following packages will be REINSTALLED:
gstreamer1.0-packagekit packagekit packagekit-tools policykit-1 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  gdm3 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for policykit-1:amd64
```

I would like your help on it because this error pops up whenever I use an apt/aptitude command.

Comment: Please use `apt` instead of `aptitude`. It often offers better solutions and I believe it's less likely to break. When packages aren't configured, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before running `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: This appears to be about Debian and not Ubuntu. While this question is off-topic here, it is on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com